# How to use rank index number to sort other set of data using loops?

Tags: matlab

I am quite new to Matlab, and am tasked to use Matlab to manage a finance/econs database.

To cut straight to the problem. Just imagine I have two sets of data, one is A and another one is B (see below). My objective is to rank the 3 columns according to value size, and then I would like to use the rank index for A (sorted_index) to position the values in B accordingly.

Below is the working but non-looping solution to obtain my answer:

```
A = [5 17 8; 11 2 9; 55 70 3; 11 8 33; 9 71 35; 9 2 3; 21 5 43; 5 2 9; 41 5 23; 61 72 91];
B = [1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 41 42 43; 51 52 53];
[A_sorted sorted_index] = sort (A);
[B_sorted sorted_indexB] = sort (B);

B_sorted (:,1) = B(sorted_index(:,1),1);
B_sorted (:,2) = B(sorted_index(:,2),2);
B_sorted (:,3) = B(sorted_index(:,3),3);
```

---

The outcome of B (sorted according to the rank position of A):
    1   12  23
    31  12  13
    1   32  3
    11  22  13
    11  42  33
    31  32  43
    21  2   33
    41  22  3
    21  2   23
    51  52  53

---

The problem is, what if I have 2000 columns instead of just 3, how can i loop successfully?

I tried this

```
for ii= size(B,2); jj= size(B,2) ; kk= size(B,2);
temp = 0*B;
temp(:,ii) = B(sorted_index(:,jj),kk);
B_sortedTest= temp;
end
```

But it only turns out to give me the correct sorted result for the last column, the first two columns are overwritten (become all zeros). Can you help me to solve the problem?

Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = [5 17 8; 11 2 9; 55 70 3; 11 8 33; 9 71 35; 9 2 3; 21 5 43; 5 2 9; 41 5 23; 61 72 91];
B = [1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 41 42 43; 51 52 53];
[A_sorted sorted_index] = sort (A);
[B_sorted sorted_indexB] = sort (B);
for i=1:size(B,2)
    B_sorted (:,i) = B(sorted_index(:,i),i);
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Zarmehi!
i just made a minor mistake, that is why I cannot proceed to get the result I want, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method without any loops:

```
A = [5 17 8; 11 2 9; 55 70 3; 11 8 33; 9 71 35; 9 2 3; 21 5 43; 5 2 9; 41 5 23; 61 72 91];
B = [1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 1 2 3; 11 12 13; 21 22 23; 31 32 33; 41 42 43; 51 52 53];
[A_sorted sorted_index] = sort (A);

% converting sorted_index into a vectorized form and having linear indices instead of subscripts i.e. 
% (row 2,column 3) in your sorted_index will be represented as 23=2*number of rows + 3=2*10+3.

linearSortedIndex=sub2ind(size(sorted_index),sorted_index(:),reshape(repmat((1:size(sorted_index,2),size(sorted_index,1),1).*ones(size(sorted_index)),[],1));

B_sorted1=reshape(B(linearSortedIndex),[],size(B,2));

%test that the result is correct

for i=1:size(B,2)
    B_sorted2(:,i) = B(sorted_index(:,i),i);
end

isequal(B_sorted1,B_sorted2) %If it prints 1, then this method is correct.
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Chandakkar for your contribution and your suggestion!
i adopted Nematollah's method, then I realise i came so close of solving had i not made that stupid mistake